# How to automate with python software sessions with assigned unique dynamic parameter?

Tags: python, dynamic, automation, pywinauto

I've tried to automate UCL Enchance tasks, but after selection of file from list each consecutive session has unique dynamic parameter for any task. I programmed using SWAPY32bit.exe tool for pywinauto. How to automate software with unique parameters for any task?

UCL Enhance Home Page - UCL Phonetics and Linguistics
[www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/enhance.php](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/enhance.php)

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

from pywinauto.timings import Timings
import time

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\SFS\\Enhance\\enhance.exe"')
afxbd = app[u'Untitled - UCLEnhance']
afxbd.Wait('ready')
time.sleep(3)
menu_item = afxbd.MenuItem(u'&File->&1 File.wav')
menu_item.Select()
time.sleep(3)
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\SFS\\Enhance\\enhance.exe"')
afxbd = app[u'File.wav - UCLEnhance']
menu_item = afxbd.MenuItem(u'&File->&Save Original &As...\tCtrl+S')
menu_item.Select()
```

Comment: Which parameter is dynamic? pywinauto can use regular expressions for window matching, but please provide more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you (tested on pywinauto 0.6.0):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\SFS\\Enhance\\enhance.exe"')
main_window = app[u'Untitled - UCLEnhance']
main_window.wait('ready')

# further actions can be done in a loop for every input file
main_window.menu_select('&File->Open...')
app.OpenDialog.Edit.set_text(ur'C:\Program Files\SFS\Enhance\six.wav')
app.OpenDialog.Open.click_input()
app.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible')

main_window = app.window(title_re='.* - UCLEnhance')
main_window.wait('ready')
# time.sleep(...) might be necessary here
main_window.Toolbar.press_button(11) # 'Enhance' button

# WM_CHECK is handled incorrectly so use WM_CLICK to check the option
app.Enhancement.SpeechLevelRadioButton.check_by_click()
app.Enhancement.OK.click()
app.Enhancement.OK.wait_not('visible')
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. SWAPY is useful for simple scenarios, but more complicated cases require reading documentation and some experience in desktop GUI automation (this is really not easy sometimes). Feel free to ask more questions.

P.P.S. Very similar and more readable code using `backend='uia'` (MS UI Automation technology):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend='uia').start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\SFS\\Enhance\\enhance.exe"')
main_window = app[u'Untitled - UCLEnhance']
main_window.wait('ready')
main_window.menu_select('&File->Open...')
main_window.OpenDialog.Edit.type_keys(ur'C:\Program Files\SFS\Enhance\six.wav{ENTER}', with_spaces=True)
main_window.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible')
main_window = app.window(title_re='.* - UCLEnhance')
main_window.wait('ready')
main_window.Toolbar.Enhance.click()

main_window.Enhancement.SpeechLevelRadioButton.invoke()
main_window.Enhancement.OK.click()
main_window.Enhancement.OK.wait_not('visible')
```